# D3 canvas globe mouse events

Tags: canvas, d3.js, mouseevent, polygon, shapes

An example of D3 canvas globe:
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4183330

What I'm trying to do is click on a country and have the globe rotate so that country is centered on the globe.

How do I do add an eventlistener (D3's .on or jQuery's .bind or plain addEventListener) to the country shapes so I can figure out which country I've clicked on?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

The example you've linked to is using the HTML5 canvas renderer.  As far as I know, it doesn't support binding click events to specific regions.

[This example uses SVG](http://bl.ocks.org/dwtkns/4686432), which is not as performant, but would allow you to bind events to each country.

Something like,

```
svg.selectAll(".countries path")
.on('click', function(d, i) {
   /* perform whatever logic here related to country associated with d */
});
```

In this case, to rotate the globe, you'll want to look at setting the projection's rotation.

Hope this helps.

## Edit

Regarding using a canvas, it might be possible to use the [d3.mouse](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-d3_mouse) wrapper along with [d3.geo.projection().invert](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Projections#wiki-invert) if your projection supports it, to figure out the projection coordinates of the mouse pointer.

At that point, you'll have to figure out if your point is 'inside' any of the countries.  That might be more difficult.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback. I built a fairly extensive example last year using an SVG globe, but the frame-rate suffered. Was trying to do it specifically with canvas for better performance. I would even go to webGL if I didn't have the restriction of supporting IE9

Comment: You might be able to overlay the canvas with some invisible paths to determine clicks.  No idea how to accomplish that though :)

Comment: I can get click events to work on the canvas itself just fine and I have been able to get some collision detection (albeit not working correctly yet), but what would be the most efficient way for me to do this, and the way I don't know how to do it - get the mouse click coordinates and translate them into the globe projection. Then all I would have to do is subtract/add the rotation of the globe against that to figure out which country I clicked on.

Comment: Some projections implement an `invert` method: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Projections#wiki-invert  Which allows you to map pixel X,Y to projection coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to John Ledbetter's answer I was able to create a working demonstration of a globe rotating to the point a user clicked on.

It doesn't solve the second part of the question, highlighting the country the user clicked on. But the code below does expose the longitude/latitude, so it's possible to build towards that solution from here.

#### Full Example

Here's a complete example of rotating to a point when a user clicks on  a transparent 3d globe on [CodePen](http://codepen.io/chrislaskey/pen/dMZEGw).

#### The Important Parts

The important pieces to doing a globe rotation when a user clicks a location on the globe are:

```
var canvas = d3.select("#map").append("canvas");

canvas.on("mousedown.drag", onMapClick);

function onMapClick() {
  rotateMap(projection.invert(d3.mouse(this)));
}

function rotateMap(p) {
  d3.transition()
    .duration(850)
    .tween("rotate", function() {
        var r = d3.interpolate(projection.rotate(), [-p[0], -p[1]]);

        return function(t) {
          projection.rotate(r(t));
          redrawMap();
        };
      })
    .transition();
}
```

The user click is converted to latitude/longitude using the `projection.invert(d3.mouse(this))`.

The rotation calculation function is created in the `d3.interpolate(projection.rotate(), [-p[0], -p[1]])` line.

And finally the globe rotation itself occurs in the tween using at the `projection.rotate(r(t))` line.

#### References

On the topic of map navigation, Jason Davie's article [Rotate the World](https://www.jasondavies.com/maps/rotate/) does a great job explaining the difficulties of navigating a 3d space with a 2d representation.